# Get child values in parent object

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have parent(Account) object and child(property__c) object.In child object i have a Date field.
i want to display child object date field values into parent object.

For this i have created same date field in parent object also,for this i used workflow,process builder but
it is not showing parent date field 
Can Any one help me on this

Comment: Can you share workflow/process builder details what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If there is lookup relationship between both two object than you can not use workflow because its not supported /working. You can use Processbuilder and in processbuilder set the reference for update record action or you can write trigger to set the date value.

```
   trigger dateUpdate on propertry__c(After Insert, After Update){
        if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
             DateupdateContoller.actionDate(Trigger.New);
       }
   }
```

-------------------Handler class ----------

```
  public class DateupdateContoller{
  public Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
  public static void actionDate( List<property__c> propList){

      if(propList != null && propList.size()>0){
            for(Property__c p : propList){
                if(p.AccountId != null){
                     AccountIds.add(p.Accountid);
                 }
            }
      }

   List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
   accList = [Select id, Date__c,(Select Id,Date__c From Properties__r) from Account WHERE ID IN : AccountIds];

   for(Account acc : accList){
        acc.Date__c = acc.Properties__r.Date__c;
    }
    if(accList != null && accList.size()>0)
        update accList;
    }
}
```